# Histogram3D frame ticks with bin text labels rendered in x-y plane?

Tags: graphics3d, charts

Is it possible in `Histogram3D` to substitute frame ticks text labels and have the layout in x-y plane?

Starting with a `Histogram3D` such as

[image]

Then combining with additional `Graphics3D` text elements, eg:

```
 Text[Style[lbl, Medium], {-1, pos + 1/2, 0}, {1, 0}, {1.5, -1}]
```

Text orientation changes with histogram rotations, and they look awful. Any ideas?

Comment: I imagine you might need to `Rasterize` your labels, then use them as a `Texture` on a `Polygon`.  But I don't know how you might show them outside the box (short of drawing your own box and axes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's something to get you started, based on wxffles' comment:

Generate a `Histogram3D`:

```
histo = Histogram3D[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 10}], {500, 2}], 
ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleCube"];
```

Generate some labels and `Rasterize` them with a specific height:

```
labels1 = Rasterize[Style[Column[DictionaryLookup["a*"][[;; 10]], Dividers -> All], 
FontFamily -> "Calibri"], ImageSize -> {{10^6}, {300}}, RasterSize -> 300];

labels2 = Rasterize[Style[Column[DictionaryLookup["z*"][[-10 ;;]], Dividers -> All], 
FontFamily -> "Calibri"], ImageSize -> {{10^6}, {300}}, RasterSize -> 300];
```

Calculate the width of the polygons to maintain the aspect ratio of the labels (in this case the polygon height will be 10 as there are 10 bins):

```
w1 = ImageDimensions[labels1][[1]]*10./300;
w2 = ImageDimensions[labels2][[1]]*10./300;
```

Put it all together:

```
Show[histo, Graphics3D[{
Texture[labels1], Polygon[{{-w1-1,0,0},{-1,0,0},{-1,10,0},{-w1-1,10,0}},
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}],
Texture[labels2], Polygon[{{0,11+w2,0},{0,11,0},{10,11,0},{10,11+w2,0}},
VertexTextureCoordinates - >{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}]
}], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1,1,0.4}, Axes -> {False, False, True},
FaceGrids -> {{{0,0,-1},{Range[0,10],Range[0,10]}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice Simon. Without something like OpenGL this will do.

Comment: Corrected for V12.0.0: Show[histo, 
 Graphics3D[{Texture[labels1], 
   Polygon[{{-w1 - 1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 10, 0}, {-w1 - 1, 10, 
      0}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
       0}, {0, 1, 0}}], Texture[labels2], 
   Polygon[{{0, 11 + w2, 0}, {0, 11, 0}, {10, 11, 0}, {10, 11 + w2, 
      0}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
       0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}, Axes -> {False, False, True}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 0, -1}, {Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}}}]

Answer (score 0):

This functions to generated something like this have changed in Mathematica.

```
histolabeled = 
 Histogram3D[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 10}], {500, 2}], 
  LabelingFunction -> Above, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleCube"]

Show[histolabeled, 
 Graphics3D[{Texture[labels1], 
   Polygon[{{-w1 - 1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 10, 0}, {-w1 - 1, 10, 
      0}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
       0}, {0, 1, 0}}], Texture[labels2], 
   Polygon[{{0, 11 + w2, 0}, {0, 11, 0}, {10, 11, 0}, {10, 11 + w2, 
      0}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
       0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}, Axes -> {False, False, True}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 0, -1}, {Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}}}]
```

[image: numbers attached to the top pf the barchart bars]

This works thanks to [`LabelingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingFunction.html) and is readable under each rotation angle from above.