# axis label and ticks alignment of ListPlot3D and Histogram3D

Tags: graphics3d, labeling

I have a question on axis label alignment of ListPlot3D and Histogram3D. These labels are not aligned with the axis of the view, but only horizontally. I have tried very hard to align them manually, but the method sucks and still the output lacks precision and neatness. I wonder if M 9.0.0 has this facility? If no, then please suggest some clean way which aligns through exact calculations.

Thanks in advance.

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
AxesLabel-> {Xaxis, Yaxis}, PlotLabel -> Sin[i + j^2], PlotStyle -> Purple]

Histogram3D[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}],
AxesLabel ->{Xaxis, Yaxis}]
```

Image by [P.Fonseca](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/78/p-fonseca)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, dude! I formatted your code. [See this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to find out how to do that yourself. It might help to explain what you did to “align them manually”, and what kind of output/alignment you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, it is useful to upload an image of your desired result somewhere. Perhaps you still lack a few reputation points to upload it by using the site's features, but someone will take care of it.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only approach that pops to my mind. We make use of texturized labels that are presented on the $x$-$y$ plane:

```
Show[
 ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
  PlotLabel -> Sin[i + j^2], PlotStyle -> Purple, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"],
 Graphics3D[{Texture[
    Rasterize[Text[Xaxis], RasterSize -> 150, ImageSize -> 150]], 
   EdgeForm[White], 
   Polygon[{{2, 0, -1}, {12, 0, -1}, {12, 5, -1}, {2, 5, -1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}],
 Graphics3D[{Texture[
    Rasterize[Text[Yaxis], RasterSize -> 150, ImageSize -> 150]], 
   EdgeForm[White], 
   Polygon[{{32, 2, -1}, {32, 12, -1}, {27, 12, -1}, {27, 2, -1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nicely done. I did something similar [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9092/862)