# How to make custom frame ticks for a Histogram3D plot

Tags: visualization, histograms, labeling

I've generated a 3D histogram using the [Histogram3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html) function and I would like to specify the frame ticks.  That is, I would like to make custom labels and locations for the rows, columns, and/or height.  For a normal 3D plot I would use FrameTicks->{{...},{...},{...}} and it's great.  But for some crazy reason the FrameTicks option is not available ("unknown") for the frame ticks of a Histgram3D (in v9). I mean, there are already frame ticks on the plot, it's just not possible to change the (often undesirable) default tick positions and labels.

Somebody asked basically this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/histogram3d-frame-ticks-with-bin-text-labels-rendered-in-x-y-plane), but the answer isn't very satisfying and that was three years ago.  Maybe there is now a better way to just do the obvious thing of customizing the frame ticks of a Histogram3D.

Comment: From Details and Options section: `Histogram3D has the same options as Graphics3D with the following additions and changes: [...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, for instance,

```
histogram = Histogram3D[data, Ticks -> {{{-2, "xLabel1"}, {0, "xLabel2"}, 
    {2, "xLabel3"}}, {{-2, "yLabel1"}, {0, "yLabel2"}, {2, "yLabel3"}}, 
   {{0, "zLabel1"}, {10, "zLabel2"}, {20, "zLabel3"}}}]
```

[image]

In general, 3D plots inherit options from `Graphics3D`, among them `Ticks`.